# Extract x,y,z coordinates of different bones using .bvh?

Tags: armature, bones

I have .bvh file and I want to write the x,y,z coordinates of different bones in different frames in a separate file. Is it possible to do this using blender?

Comment: You should be able to extract the information you want without Blender, only using Python. You may use Blender's integrated Python and the text editor as some kind of IDE if you want however. Have a look at the BVH import script to get an idea how to parse the BVH file format.

Comment: @CoDEmanX How can we look at import script?

Comment: Well, go to your Blender folder and locate the addons sub-folder with the BVH import script, e.g. `Blender\2.73\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh` and open them in a code editor like Notepad++.